# How to display a something from an EditText?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I thought making thing part of the app would be easy, however I was wrong. I wish to have a textView display whatever the user wrote in the editText. This is what I tried.

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myTextView.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());
    // of course I would use variables in place of the
        // myTextView and myEditText
    }
});
```

This is another way I tried to get this done.

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //num1 is my String variable
        num1 = myEditText.getText().toString();
    myTextView.setText(num1);
    }
});
```

Both times the textView comes up with nothing in it.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: I guess you are instantiate the EditText component. What code you have used to get references of TextView and EditText?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `GetDlgItemText`.

```
char Buffer[120];
GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, (control), buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

This will read it and store it in buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`onClickListener` merely responds to user clicks. You need to implement a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on your `EditText`. The most straightforward way of doing this is to *implement* `TextWatcher` in your class, then make a call to `myEditText.addTextChangedListener(this)`.

I recommend adding something like the following to your `onTextChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    myTextView.setText(myTextView.getText()+s);//or something like this...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the EditText the getText call should you return the String, I don't believe you need to call the ToString method on it.  The way you are using it in the onClickListener implies you have a button that should be calling a function to set the text into the textview.  If you want it dynamically you should be able to use onTextChanged to fill in the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether the control is coming to your setOnClickListener(). Put in a Log to find that out.

Next make sure that "add" is the button or item that u r using to initiate the copy process.

This statement of yours is correct.

```
myTextView.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());
```

Though you do not require the toString(). Doesnt really make a difference. I suggest you check that your textview and edittext is fine.

Answer (score 0):

have you check the visibility of textview ?before clicking add button it is invisible rite?then u have to set the visibility on add button click.

Answer (score 0):

From your code i understood that there is a button here too so try this should work:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
            btn.setOnClickListener(btncall);
}

  private OnClickListener btncall = new OnClickListener()
  {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
      TextView mytextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MytextView);   
      EditText myeditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyeditText);
      mytextView.setText(myeditText.getText().toString());
      }
  };
```

}